# Oracle: Replace first character to other character

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in oracle in which we have one column having data as `B12345`, means first alphabet always `B` and followed by numeric. I want to replace all such instances with `BH` that will become `BH12345`

So if already there is a value called **BH**45678 in that column don't update.

Only where find B followed by numeric need updates.

Comment: Do you want to update the table data, or just adjust the select result?

Comment: Please define "B followed by numeric" - does that mean B, followed by a digit, followed by other characters? Or do ALL the remaining characters have to be digits? In other words, is an input like B123Z possible, and if it is possible, should the B be changed to BH or not?

Comment: B always be followed by digits I mentioned.

Comment: So if it's B123Z, then it should remain unchanged? In that case vkp's answer is the proper solution.

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the rows which have `B` followed by digits using `regexp_like`. Then use `replace` to replace `B` with `BH` for those rows.

```
select replace(col,'B','BH')
from tablename
where regexp_like(col,'^B\d+$')
```

Comment: I read the requirement differently (whenever the start of the string is B followed by a digit followed by anything else, insert the H in the second position). I asked the OP in a comment to clarify.

Comment: @mathguy..this is not something new.. you always be a great hurry and mostly don't read or understand questions completely

Comment: @vkp..+1 for quick one.

Comment: @Raj_Te - can you explain please? What do you mean? How did I not read or understand the question completely? I thought I did until I saw vkp's answer and I realized the words may be interpreted in a different way. As regards "always be a great hurry" - just go back to my contributions to this site, you will see that very often I ask for clarification before I post anything.

Comment: Guys please don't fight this is resolved, thanks for all help and I up votes you also.

Answer (score 2):

```
with
     inputs( str ) as (
       select 'B123' from dual union all
       select 'BONE' from dual union all
       select 'BH55' from dual union all
       select 'Z123' from dual union all
       select 'B13H' from dual
     )
select str, regexp_replace(str, '^B(\d)', 'BH\1') as new_str
from   inputs
;

STR  NEW_STR
---- -------
B123 BH123
BONE BONE
BH55 BH55
Z123 Z123
B13H BH13H

5 rows selected.
```